# mongoose findOneAndUpdate returns updated document but doesn't update database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Consider the following mongoose query:

```
mongoose.model(collection).findOneAndUpdate({[fieldName]: fieldValue}, {$set:{processed:1}}, {new:true}, function(err, doc){
    console.log(doc);
    callback(err, doc);
});
```

This returns the document with the property `processed:1` although, it does not update the mongodb table.

I do not set on the mongoose schema the processed property. so the schema would be something like:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('collection', {
    _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    parm1:{type: String},
    parm2:{type: Number},
    parm3:{type: String, index:true}
}, 'mycollection');
```

Is there any option I can set so that it returns the updated document at the same time it updates the database record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose can only update the table with the defined fields in schema. So, if the `processed` field does not exist in Mongoose schema, it won't update the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `strict` option property on update. This will overwrites the schema and make possible to you to add any attribute you want that's not in the defined schema.

`model.findOneAndUpdate(where, data, { ...options, strict: true });`

See: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict